# SQL SELECT Between 2 Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am having a real issue with trying to query my database by selecting the data between 2 dates.

Below is the query I am using within my VB .NET project.

`WHERE [BuildID] > 0 AND [EndDate] BETWEEN '01/07/2014' and '31/07/2014'`

The date format is set to dd/mm/yyyy and the column type is VARCHAR(10)

When I run this query, it brings back all the data in my database, basically it selects all.

I have tried several methods such as `[EndDate] >= '01/07/2014' and [EndDate] <= '31/07/2014'` and it brings back the same result, it disregards the dates and brings back the entire database.

I have a feeling that it is because the column is set to VARCHAR but I am not sure.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be most helpful.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the date in yyyyMMdd format? You will never get it wrong that way.

Comment: for date comparison using strings, always use YYYY/MM/dd format - year first followed by month followed by date.

Comment: Why have a datetime value stored in a `VARCHAR(10)` field? If you only want the date portion, either use `DATE` data type available in SQL 2008 and up, or use a `DATETIME` stripping the time portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The column type is `VARCHAR(10)`

To have dates treated as dates, you'd need the column type to be `date` (or `datetime` if using older versions of SQL).

If you don't have control over the column type, you'd need to cast to date, but that's going to perform badly with any sizable data set:

```
WHERE [BuildID] > 0 
AND cast([EndDate] as date) BETWEEN '2014-07-01' and '2014-07-31'
```

NB: I also changed the date format of the strings above - that's not required, but it's my preference to avoid confusion between US and UK formats (especially useful if your code's maintained by an international team).

Answer (score 1):

Try `yyyyMMdd` format which will never fail. You should also try converting your column to `DATETIME`.

```
WHERE [BuildID] > 0 AND CONVERT(DATETIME,[EndDate]) BETWEEN '20140701' and '20140731'
```

or if you have a variable in your VB then :

```
dateVar.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Answer (score 1):

At first change the column type to date or if you need the time too, use datetime.

Then you can use the T-SQL Function `CONVERT` to change your submitted Value to the right Time/Datetime Format.

[T-SQL Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Refer **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3)**  for date time formats in SQL Server

Use something like:

```
convert(varchar,EndDate,111)  BETWEEN '2014/07/01' and '2014/07/31'
```

Because, varchar does string comparison and will fail in dd/mm/yyyy format. String comparison works best in yyyy/mm/dd (YearMonthDate) format.

```
Example, as per varchar comparison,

31/01/2014 is greater than 01/02/2014
whereas,
2014/01/31 is lesser than 2014/02/01.
```

Comment: @jyparask: I dont have experience with SQL Server, may be you can try, convert `string(dd/mm/yyyy)->date->string(yyyy/mm/dd)` format. In oracle it would be like, `TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE (MY_VALUE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') , 'YYYY/MM/DD' );` Change syntax as per SQL Server norms

Comment: In order for this to work you should do it like : `convert(varchar,convert(datetime,103),111)`. This way you convert the expected string to datetime and then convert it buck to string. But this is too much, isn't it?

Comment: @jyparask: I dont think there is a way out. Either you have to maintain in DB as Date format or in DB as yyyy/mm/dd format. The workaround which I know is this.

Answer (score 1):

Always **always** use [parameterized SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i).

```vb
Dim date1 As Date = Date.Parse("2014-07-01")
Dim date2 As Date = Date.Parse("2014-07-31")

mycmd.CommandText = ".... WHERE [BuildID] > @bid AND [EndDate] BETWEEN @firstDate AND @lastDate"
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", 0I)
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstDate", date1)
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastDate", date2)
```